# Making sure primary and secondary keys align in POSTGRES

Tags: sql, postgresql, join, foreign-keys, left-join

I am trying to join a primary key to a secondary key. The dimension table has limited records/very few and the fact table has over 5 million. I just can't get these column in sync so that I can do a left join. I tried several ways, please assist?

```
-- Table: system.IMETA_ZTRB_MP$F_ZTBR_TA_BW

-- DROP TABLE IF EXISTS system."IMETA_ZTRB_MP$F_ZTBR_TA_BW";

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS system."IMETA_ZTRB_MP$F_ZTBR_TA_BW"
(
    "ZTBR_TransactionCode" text COLLATE pg_catalog."default" NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('"ZTBR_TransactionCode_Seq"'::regclass),
    "Company_Code" text COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    "Posting_Period" integer,
    "Fiscal_Year" integer,
    "Profit_Center" text COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    "Account_Number" text COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    "Business_Process" text COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    "Cost_Center" text COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    "Internal_Order" text COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    "Trading_Partner" text COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    "Amount_in_Company_Code_Currency" numeric,
    "Company_Code_Currency" text COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    "BRACS_FA" text COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    "Expense_Type" text COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    "BRACS_ACCT_Key" text COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    "CC_Direct" text COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    "Segment_PC" text COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    "CC_Master_FA" text COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    "Region_Secondary_Key" integer NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('system."IMETA_ZTRB_MP$F_ZTBR_TA_BW_Region_Secondary_Key_seq1"'::regclass),
    "Direct_Indirect_Secondary_Key" integer NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('system."IMETA_ZTRB_MP$F_ZTBR_TA_BW_Direct_Indirect_Secondary_Key_seq1"'::regclass),
    "Source_Description_Secondary_Key" integer NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('system."IMETA_ZTRB_MP$F_ZTBR_TA_BW_Source_Description_Secondary_Ke_seq1"'::regclass),
    "Entity_Secondary_Key" integer,
    "Master_BRACS_Secondary_Key" integer,
    CONSTRAINT "IMETA_ZTRB_MP$F_ZTBR_TA_BW_pkey" PRIMARY KEY ("ZTBR_TransactionCode"),
    CONSTRAINT fk_entity FOREIGN KEY ("Entity_Secondary_Key")
        REFERENCES dim."IMETA_Entity_Mapping" ("Entity_ID") MATCH SIMPLE
        ON UPDATE NO ACTION
        ON DELETE NO ACTION,
    CONSTRAINT fk_master_bracs_secondary_key FOREIGN KEY ("Master_BRACS_Secondary_Key")
        REFERENCES dim."IMETA_Master_BRACS_to_SAP_Data_TA_BR_" ("Primary_ZTBR_TransactionCode") MATCH SIMPLE
        ON UPDATE NO ACTION
        ON DELETE NO ACTION
)

TABLESPACE pg_default;

ALTER TABLE IF EXISTS system."IMETA_ZTRB_MP$F_ZTBR_TA_BW"
    OWNER to apollia;

-- Trigger: sync_bracs_keys_trigger

-- DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS sync_bracs_keys_trigger ON system."IMETA_ZTRB_MP$F_ZTBR_TA_BW";

CREATE TRIGGER sync_bracs_keys_trigger
    BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE 
    ON system."IMETA_ZTRB_MP$F_ZTBR_TA_BW"
    FOR EACH ROW
    EXECUTE FUNCTION public.sync_bracs_keys();
    ----------
    -- Table: dim.IMETA_Master_BRACS_to_SAP_Data_TA_BR_

-- DROP TABLE IF EXISTS dim."IMETA_Master_BRACS_to_SAP_Data_TA_BR_";

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS dim."IMETA_Master_BRACS_to_SAP_Data_TA_BR_"
(
    "Acct Type" character varying(255) COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    "Level 1" character varying(255) COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    "Level 2" character varying(255) COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    "Level 3" character varying(255) COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    "GCoA" double precision,
    "Account Desc" character varying(255) COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    "EXPENSE FLAG" character varying(255) COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    "BRACS" double precision,
    "BRACS_DESC" character varying(255) COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    "Loaddate" date,
    "Primary_ZTBR_TransactionCode" integer NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('dim."IMETA_Master_BRACS_to_SAP_Data_Primary_ZTBR_TransactionCode_seq"'::regclass),
    CONSTRAINT "IMETA_Master_BRACS_to_SAP_Data_TA_BR__pkey" PRIMARY KEY ("Primary_ZTBR_TransactionCode")
)

TABLESPACE pg_default;

ALTER TABLE IF EXISTS dim."IMETA_Master_BRACS_to_SAP_Data_TA_BR_"
    OWNER to ;
```

I tried:

```
"-- Step 1: Drop existing foreign key constraint for Entity
ALTER TABLE system."IMETA_ZTRB_MP$F_ZTBR_TA_BW" DROP CONSTRAINT IF EXISTS fk_entity;

-- Step 2: Drop and recreate secondary key for Entity, setting it to null by default
ALTER TABLE system."IMETA_ZTRB_MP$F_ZTBR_TA_BW"
DROP COLUMN IF EXISTS "Entity_Secondary_Key",
ADD COLUMN "Entity_Secondary_Key" INTEGER;

-- Step 3: Update secondary key for Entity based on primary key from the dimension table
UPDATE system."IMETA_ZTRB_MP$F_ZTBR_TA_BW" AS fact
SET "Entity_Secondary_Key" = dim2."Entity_ID"
FROM dim."IMETA_Entity_Mapping" AS dim2
WHERE fact."Entity_Secondary_Key" = dim2."Entity_ID";

-- Step 4: Re-add foreign key constraint for Entity
ALTER TABLE system."IMETA_ZTRB_MP$F_ZTBR_TA_BW"
ADD CONSTRAINT fk_entity FOREIGN KEY ("Entity_Secondary_Key") REFERENCES dim."IMETA_Entity_Mapping"("Entity_ID");
```

I tried to create triggers for inserting new rows and also increment update of rows. The foreign key in the fact table will then contain nulls (greyed out) or it will update with very high values.

Comment: Hi - can you clarify what you mean by getting these columns in sync? It’s very unclear, to me, what the issue is and what end result you are trying to achieve. Maybe update your question with sample data (for the relevant columns) and the result you want

Comment: Dimension table has 50 records and Fact table 5 million. Meaning that 50 columns must be link to the secondary key in the fact table. My dimension table is suppose to give rule to the secondary key in the fact table.

Comment: Hi - that comment doesn't seem to explain anything. Why does the number of records mean that columns (in which table?) must link to a secondary key? What do you mean by a secondary key - do you mean a foreign key? Dimension tables don't "give rule" (whatever that means) to keys in another table. I'm guessing that there should be a foreign key in the fact table that references the dimension but there is some data issue that is stopping you from creating this FK. If this is the case then can you update your question to explain how this issue should be fixed?

Comment: Yes, i mean creating relationships among the tables.

Comment: I am not getting any data for the dimension table, when doing a Left join and no data for fact table when doing a Right join. I have altered the contraints between the tables quite a few times. https://drive.google.com/file/d/1sZcps64FKna1QNX7PpJT2LDv5jRpxKkc/view?usp=sharing, https://drive.google.com/file/d/13Hf5P3T0c2vsW_56RNBq_rKCFgcgU5Am/view?usp=sharing

Comment: So how do you know what the correct value is, from the DIM PK column, to update each fact record FK? Also, don't link to random URLs that no-one with any knowledge of security would click on. If you want to set up an example please use dbfiddle

Comment: GOAL IS "When you don't have a direct key to join tables, you need to create a set of conditions that can reliably map one row in the first table to a row in the second table. This involves using business rules or combinations of other columns that can serve as a "composite" key for joining."